# Automatically adding new post categories to menu

Tags: php, functions, menus, walker

Disclaimer: I am not 100% fluent in php. If I am doing something wrong in asking this here, please let me know. Many thanks!

A site that I am working on is set up with several custom post types: City, State, Foreign, Topic, etc. The menu lists these, as well as posts by date, so the menu looks like this:

City   State   Foreign   Topics   Date

I am trying to find a way to automatically update a site menu whenever a new post category is created (a new month/year, a new city, a new Topic, etc.)

Right now, I have to add each new month/year to the menu manually, and if a new category is created (ex., “Florida” under “State”, or March 2021 blog posts), I have to add it to the menu manually.

I tried to add code using the link below as guide, but it isn’t working. You can see the code, it is live right now. What am I doing wrong? is there an easier way to do this? I tried finding a plugin to handle this and came up empty (https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-auto-menu exists, but it isn’t working for folks and hasn’t been updated in a year.) THANK YOU!

[Add custom taxonomy terms to Wordpress menu dynamically & append #slug to url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/327905/add-custom-taxonomy-terms-to-wordpress-menu-dynamically-append-slug-to-url)

```
class Walker_State_Categories extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    // we only need to override the function that closes each menu item,
    // this is where we can insert a submenu
    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array() ) {
        // if the current menu item being output is state
        if( 'State' == $item->title ){
            // get all of the state categories
            $State_cats = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'State_categories',
                'hide_empty' => false,
            ) );
            if ( ! empty( $State_cats ) && ! is_wp_error( $State_cats ) ) {
                // url of the state page
                // to be used to append #anchor links
                $parent_url = get_permalink( $item->object_id );
                // start a new list
                $output .= '<ul>';
                // iterate over each category
                // and add an li
                foreach( $State_cats as $State_cat ){
                    $slug = $State_cat->slug;
                    $name = $State_cat->name;
                    $format = '<li><a href="%s#%s">%s</a></li>';
                    $output .= sprintf( $format, $parent_url, $slug, $name );
                }
                // close the list
                $output .= '</ul>';
            }
        }
        // close the parent li
        $output .= "</li>\n";  
    }
}
```